# Extract a string of words between two specific characters in R, nested in ifelse()

Tags: stringr

I would like to create a new variable (cPI) based the format of an existing variable (PI_NAMEs). PI_NAMEs contains a combination of a single name and multiple names. When multiple names are present, one is distinguished as the 'contact', but where the contact appears in the full list of multiple names varies. When there are multiple names, I do know that the contact PI name is contained between a ';' and '(contact)'. When there is only a single name, that name is assumed this is the contact.

I am using the dplyr and stringr packages and cant quite the following code to work properly.

Also, below are a few rows of the PI_NAMEs variable. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

#### A FEW DATALINES

> [950] MILLER, TIMOTHY A;
>   [951] DOULATOV, SERGEI ;                                                                                                  > [952] FIELDS, NOELLE  (contact); XU, LING ;
>   [953] LEE, SHOOU-YIH DANIEL;
>   [954] JAKOBS, THOMAS ;
>   [955] MIWA, JULIE M.; WHITEAKER, PAUL  (contact);
>   [956] GANESH, SANTHI K;
>   [957] VONDRISKA, THOMAS M.;
>   [958] SHAPIRO, LAWRENCE S;
>   [959] APPLING, ANTHONY ;
>   [960] CHEN, HORNG H;
>   [961] MCNAMARA, JAMES O.;
>   [962] STATES, J CHRISTOPHER;
>   [963] BONNEAU, RICHARD A; CHRISTIAEN, LIONEL  (contact); SATIJA, RAHUL ;
>   [964] SUBRAMANIAN, NAEHA ;
>   [965] LEONG, DANIEL J (contact); SUN, HUI BIN;
>   [966] FERNANDEZ-LIMA, FRANCISCO ;
>   [967] GRAY, BRIAN DAVID; LIU, ZHONGLIN  (contact);

`NEW_GRANT <- mutate(NEW_GRANT, cPI = ifelse(str_detect(as.character(NEW_GRANT$PI_NAMEs), pattern="(contact)"), str_extract(string=as.character(NEW_GRANT$PI_NAMEs), pattern = "(?<=;).*?=(contact)"), str_extract(string=as.character(NEW_GRANT$PI_NAMEs))))`

Error: Evaluation error: argument "pattern" is missing, with no default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code above is you do not have a pattern argument in the last str_exact.
Why not just export the value in NEW_GRANT$PI_NAMEs when only value is under PI name?